# Requesting a BigQuery API from Google Spreadsheet generates an Error

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch data from Bigquery and show them into my spreadsheet using the App script. First, I created a Spreadsheet file in my G-drive and then put my code into the script editor.

Here is the code I have used to get all the datasets from Bigquery:

```
    function getAllDataSets(filter){
  try{
    let req_for_datasets = BigQuery.Datasets.list(PROJECT_ID);
    let datasets = req_for_datasets.datasets;
    let list = [];
    datasets.forEach( obj => {
      if(obj.datasetReference.datasetId.indexOf(filter)>-1) 
        list.push(obj.datasetReference.datasetId);
    });
    return list;
  }catch(e){
    return [];
  }
}
```

this script works fine and I can see the result while running my script through Code Editor. I try to use this script in onOpen() or onEdit() to be able to get data when the spreadsheet gets opened.
but using the spreadsheet I receive this message:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.tables.list failed with error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

this is the code I have put in onOpen function:

```
    function onOpen(){
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let method_list = ["SUM", "AVG", "COUNT"];
  //Adding a Custom menu
  ui.createMenu("Media Budget")
    .addItem("Facebook", "makeQuery")
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem("Google Ads", "makeQuery")
    .addToUi();

    
  //Getting all datasets from the specified project
  let dataset_list = getAllDataSets("dw_sandbox_");
  Browser.msgBox(dataset_list);
  //Creating dropdown list cell
  let cell = SHEET.getRange("B1");
  applyValidationToCell(dataset_list, cell);
  
}
```

other than that if I try to execute the function using the custom menu in the spreadsheet everything works fine as well.

It would be really appreciated if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you can perform a request when running code manualy, but not on simple onOpen or onEdit trigger - the reason is authorization issues

See [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user
> for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions:
>
> ...
>
> **They cannot access services that require authorization**. For example, a
> simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
> authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
> Language service, which is anonymous.

### Workaround

- **Option a)**

  Rather than running the request `onOpen`, implement it into a separate function that will be called when chosen from custom menu

  Sample:

```js
function onOpen(){
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let method_list = ["SUM", "AVG", "COUNT"];
  //Adding a Custom menu
  ui.createMenu("Media Budget")
  .addItem("Facebook", "makeQuery")
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem("Google Ads", "makeQuery")
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem("bigQuery", "makeBigQuery")
  .addToUi();  
}

function makeBigQuery(){
  //Getting all datasets from the specified project
  let dataset_list = getAllDataSets("dw_sandbox_");
  Browser.msgBox(dataset_list);
  //Creating dropdown list cell
  let cell = SHEET.getRange("B1");
    applyValidationToCell(dataset_list, cell);
}
```

- **Option b)**

  Run your exisitng code on [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead on simple trigger.
- Installable triggers can run funcitons that reuire auhtorization
- To convert your simple trigger into an installable

  - rename the function from `onOpen` (otherisw you might run into conflicts from having both simple and installable triggers run simultaneously)
  - Go on `Edit -> Current project's triggers - > New trigger` -  see also [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)